# Don't remove active class style hovering over menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I've got a project where different clients have their own themes (html color codes saved in the sql database). Once they log on I change the theme (menu and footer colours). Thus the theme itself stays consistent, with only the colours changing.

In my Master page I've added some js code to auto change depending on who is loggeed in. Hovering and moving out of the menu item is working fine. Setting the active menu item is also working, provided that you don't hover over the active menu item. If you do hover over the active menu item, the style is removed from the active menu item.

This is what I've done:

```
    $('.navigation').css({ "background": "#" + primaryColor });
        $('.navigation ul li a').css({ "color": "#" + primaryTextColor });

        $(".navigation ul li a").hover(function () {
            $(this).css({ "background": "#" + secondaryColor, "color": "#" + secondaryTextColor });
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css({ "background": "#" + primaryColor, "color": "#" + primaryTextColor });
        });

    id = (function () {
            return f = window.location.href.split('/').pop().split('.')[0];
        })

    $("#mi" + id()).css({ "background": "#" + secondaryColor, "color": "#" + secondaryTextColor });
```

The menu item is built this way:

```
    <div class="navigation">            
        <ul id="liHome" runat="server" >
            <li id="miDefault" ><a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
            <li id="miScanDocuments" ><a href="ScanDocuments.aspx">Scan Document</a></li>
            <li id="miViewDocument" ><a href="ViewDocument.aspx">View Document</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

I gather that the style is removed on the mouseout event. Is there any way that I can prevent the style from being removed if the current page is the active menu item?

Comment: why use js to do something css can do?  It may be easier to create a dynamic stylesheet using c#

Comment: @Pete, Please add your comment as an answer? Dynamic stylesheet is working perfect...

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:not()` CSS pseudo-class in your `$(".navigation ul li a")`so `$(".navigation ul li a:(.current)")` and of course you'd need to add the class before hand so you could update your id function to addClass of 'current' as your first function. I.e. just binding to the elements you want so it shouldn't run when you hover over the current menu item.

Comment: Thank you, but adding current/hover as mentioned doesn't work on my side which is why I used the .hover and .mouseout event....